# how to extract a record in a text on string match in a file using windows bash

Tags: windows, bash

Hi i have a text file sampple.txt as

```
    =====record1
    title:javabook
    price:$120
    author:john
    path:d:
    =====record2
    title:.netbook
    author:paul
    path:f:
    =====record3
    author:john
    title:phpbook
    subject:php
    path:f:
    price:$150
    =====record4
    title:phpbook
    subject:php
    path:f:
    price:$150
```

from this i want to split the data based on author, it should split into 2 files which contains

```
test1.txt

=====record1
    title:javabook
    price:$120
    author:john
    path:d:
=====record3
    author:john
    title:phpbook
    subject:php
    path:f:
    price:$150
```

and

```
test2.txt

=====record2
    title:.netbook
    author:paul
    path:f:
```

like above i want to classify the main sample.txt file into sub files based on author field dynamically please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: should the `===recordx` lines also be in output files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk -F: '{a[++i]=$0;if(i==3)f=$2}i==4{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[x]>f".txt";i=0}' file
```

this line will name the output file with the author's name. And if the name has space, you have to quote it.   If you need a numbered text file, it is also easy, just create an array during reading lines. something like:

```
f['John']=1
f['Tom']=2
f['Jerry']=3
...
```

this line is just show how would it work.

with your content in `file` as example:

```
kent$  awk -F: '{a[++i]=$0;if(i==3)f=$2}i==4{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[x]>f".txt";i=0}' file

kent$  head *.txt
==> john.txt <==
=====record1
title:javabook
author:john
path:d:
=====record3
title:javabook
author:john
path:f:

==> paul.txt <==
=====record2
title:.netbook
author:paul
path:f:
```

Comment: Thanks its working great, can u please explain me the command , because for this text file only it is working but i want to extract data from files where fields positions and no of filelds not constant, some records may have 3,4 fields and some may have 6,7 fields,based on the "Author" string it should retrieve the whole record, is this possible? can u please suggest me how to do it for that kind of files?

Comment: please find the modified question also(changed my sample.txt file)